# How to make the cancel button of a searchBar accessible ?

Tags: swift, keyboard, accessibility, voiceover, searchbar

I have a searchbar, that opens a keyboard when selected.

The issue is, when I use VoiceOver, the keyboard stays open even when moving on to another element. For that, I wish to use the cancel button of the searchbar and make it appear only if accessibility is used, but when I make it appear, VoiceOver does not read it.

How can I make it accessible ? Or do you know any other way to handle properly the keyboard of a searchbar with VoiceOver ?

```swift
public func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning() {
        self.searchBar?.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    }
}

public func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchBar?.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

Comment: Some news about this?